# Unable to update Ubuntu 16.04 through apt-get update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, updates

In the last couple of months, I was unable to connect to WiFi though Ubuntu 16.04; only connecting with the Ethernet cable worked.

Here is [my wireless info made by the wireless script](https://pastebin.com/A129bx41) if that's of any help.

I figured it must be because of drivers so I run `apt-get update` and got this error:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjasnik/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]      
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]    
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]      
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:13 https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease [3.590 B]
Ign:13 https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Fetched 326 kB in 3s (98,8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
W: The repository 'https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Nothing in the error messages indicates a driver problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you have described here: https://spout.ussg.indiana.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/ for the repository for R you should install the key (section Secure ATP):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

and after that do

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

If the key is installed correctly, everything will be works well.

Comment: Congratulations Sherlock!  **;-)**  +1